# Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'Data' rather than 'Task<Data>'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await

```
 public async Task<Data> GetData()
    {
        Task<Data> data = null;

        //This data will be fetched from DB
        Data obj = new Data();
        obj.ID = 1;
        obj.Name = "Test";

        //Need to 
        // data = obj;

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return obj;
        });

    }
```

> Error 1   Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'WebApplication2.Data' rather than 'Task'    \inb-fs01\Users\user\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Home.aspx.cs  35  20  WebApplication2

Can someone help me sorting out this issue?

Comment: You will also need an `await` somewhere... The sample is too artificial (simplified) to give a good answer.

Comment: Why put `async` on a method that doesn't do any asynchronous work?

Comment: What does `data = obj` buy you if it's commented out?

Answer (score 18):

Change your code to `await Task.Run`. I.e.

```
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return obj;
    });
```

The compiler generates a state machine for `async` methods so for a method returning `Task<T>`, you actually return `T` and the compiler wraps it in a `Task` in the generated state machine.

I assume this is some sort of exercise or a simplified example as the method does not need to be `async` at all.

Comment: Even if something actually happened inside Task.Run, the OP could still return the Task withouth using `async/await`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _Unless_ what happens inside Task.Run is `await`ed. Then `async` is required, and the return value within the method's body must remain an unwrapped `Data` for the method to properly return `Task<Data>`. I think it's that implicit wrapping Neddy mentions of `Data` to `Task<Data>` that `async` essentially performs that's confusing the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Well, "*since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type `Data` rather than `Task<Data>`*".

So, change this:

```
return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return obj;
    });
```

to this:

```
return obj;
```

Also, why are you making this method async in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

I'll agree with the other answers - this example is too artificial to give a good answer. There is really no reason to put `async` on a method that just wants to return an object.

`async\await` by themselves don't make a method run asynchronously, it's only syntactic sugar that allows awaiting for already asynchronous operations to complete.

Just for completeness, the following options should be considered as well:

- Return a Task object without using `async/await` at all. If the method doesn't have anything to do after Task.Run, there is no reason to await.

  ```
  public Task<Data> GetData()
  {
      ....
      return Task.Run(() =>
      {
          //Do something time consuming
          return obj;
      });
  }
  ```
- Don't use Task.Run if all that's needed is to return a piece of data. Use [Task.FromResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to return a pre-computed task. This assumes that the callers of the method really need it to return a Task, otherwise this example should be converted to a plain method

  ```
  public Task<Data> GetData()
  {
      ....
      return Task.FromResult(obj);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

if you write asp.net core

return await GetData();

Answer (score 1):

Where ever u are calling this function, try to put await before that call, like below:

```
Data obj = await GetData();
```

And return `Data` object simply from `GetData()` method.

Comment: The problem is *inside* the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return Task.FromResult(obj);
```